# How to find the first set of character that does not contain repeated character stand next to each other in a string

Tags: java

I have tried like in the code below but it only work if there is only one character set and the character set appear in the middle of the string. If the set appear more than once and appear at the end or the start of the string, the result is false.

```
    String str = "aaabbccdddefghjjkklmn";

for(int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1) && str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)){
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

With the string above, the result should be "efgh" only but the code above display "efghlm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue causing you to miss the beginning and end values is the way you constructed the for loop.

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

You therefore need to handle the edge cases differently.

```
if ( (i+1 >= str.length() || str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1)) && (i-1 < 0 || str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)) )
```

This way, you are including the first and last indices without accessing out of range. Additionally, if you want to ensure that you only get the first instance of characters, you need some code to break out of the loop. Assign a boolean to true when the check returns true. If the check returns false, check to see if your found boolean is true. If so, break out of the loop.

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if ( (i+1 >= str.length() || str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1)) && (i-1 < 0 || str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)) ) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        foundMatch = true;
    }
    else {
        if (foundMatch == true) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct. Just that you need to break the loop once repeating character is found, AFTER you found the first set of non-repeating characters.

Below snippet is JavaScript equivalent of your code

```js
 var str = "aaabbccdddefghjjkklmn";

var result = "";
for(var i = 1; i < str.length - 1; i++){
    // Find for non-repeating character
    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1) && str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)){
        result += str.charAt(i)
    }
    else {
      // Repeating character found
      // exit loop if non-repeating character already
      // found
      if (result.length > 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This still does not handle the possibility of the characters at indices 0 or str.length -1 are not repeats of their neighbors.